# How did this character get there?

Tags: miss-peregrines-home

I recently watched [Miss Peregrine's Home for Peculiar Children](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1935859/?ref_=nv_sr_1) and couldn't figure out how, at the end of the movie,

> Jake made it to Florida.

The character was alone, in the past, and without money.  The movie gave no clues, as he was simply sitting there on the pier, and in the next scene was arriving at his destination.  Was there something I missed, or perhaps something in the book to explain this?

Answer (score 1):

He was not in the past, the final battle is set in 2016, out of any loophole.

As he changed the past, he is in a timeline where his grandfather is still alive, and after the others returned to the loophole via the train, he proceeded to search for other loopholes (possibly with his grandfather's help).

Comment: He was in the past, though.  The loop he left from was in January 2016, while he first entered a loop in September 2016.  I get why his grandfather is still alive, but being a teenager with no money stranded in a foreign country while his other self must be in Florida still... How does he manage to get to Florida?

Comment: Well, he could just phone his grandfather (borrowing somones phone is not too complicated), explain the situation to him and get some money from him, and then wait for 6 month from his "other self" to disapear.

But in this timeline, his "other self" hasn't got any reason to disapear... So, time paradox... Well, thanks, now I have a headache ^^

Comment: Yes, he could phone his grandfather.  He could find some change and gamble it to enough money to buy a plane ticket.  He could stowaway on a boat.  But what did he actually do?